# Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm following a tutorial online on how to make a to do list. found here

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MURDw0-BiEE

I've following it perfectly, but it won't work. Browser states the 'appendChild' is null. The tutorial is 2 years old, is it just script that has been outdated?

Really appreciate the help

```
function addNewItem() {
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.innerText = "Hello";

    list.appendChild(listItem);
}

var btnNew = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
btnNew.onclick = function() {
    addNewItem(document.getElementById("todoList"));
};
```

and here's the related part of the html

```
<p><button id="btnAdd">New Item</button></p>

<ul id="todolist">
</ul>

<script src="todo.js"></script>
```

Comment: You need to show your own code, not what you say you've followed "perfectly." Without the code you're actually running, we can't troubleshoot anything for you. FWIW, no, the code in the video is not outdated--it'll work fine.

Comment: where is `list` defined?

Answer (score 4):

You wrote `addNewItem` and invoked it in a manner which expects that it should take a parameter named `list` but you never added it as a param in the function definition. This should straighten you up:

```
function addNewItem(list) {
```

as opposed to your

```
function addNewItem() {
```