# appendChild null | javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm following a tutorial online on how to make a to do list, found here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MURDw0-BiEE

I've following it pretty closely, but it won't work. Browser states the `appendChild` is null. The tutorial is 2 years old, could a part of the code be outdated? I had it sending alerts through the button, but when I changed to the `appendChild` things stopped working.

I'm pretty new to this and really appreciate the help.

```
function addNewItem() {
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.innerText = "Hello";

    list.appendChild(listItem);
}


var btnNew = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
btnNew.onclick = function() {
    addNewItem(document.getElementById("todoList"));
};
```

And here's the related part of the HTML:

```
<p><button id="btnAdd">New Item</button></p>

<ul id="todolist">


</ul>

<script src="todo.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: where is the variable `list` in `addNewItem()` defined?

Comment: function addNewItem(list) | There we go, still doesn't work though

Comment: You might also take some time to learn how your browser's debugger works. With a good debugger, you can step through the code to the point where the error occurs and even inspect the value of variables along the way. Just google for your browser name and then the word "debugger". Hope this helps.

Comment: You ***[already asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226721/cannot-read-property-appendchild-of-null-javascript)*** and ignored the people who responded to you!

Comment: I asked the same question but no one answered it, I'm new to stackoverflow and didn't know how to properly ask a question. I'm learning, and y'all have been more than helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined your function without arguments and then you try to pass one  :

```
function addNewItem(list) {}
```

***P.S.*** : You also tried to `getElementById` `todoList` instead of `todolist`, so it also gave you error :

```
addNewItem(document.getElementById("todolist"));
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P3ZLv/2/)

Comment: @user3509140: Then why did you leave a comment above saying that changing it to `function addNewItem(list)` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a parameter to the function addNewItem() with `addNewItem(document.getElementById("todoList"))`, but you aren't declaring this parameter in your function. So the variable list becomes null and appendChild() does not work. So change your first line:

```
function addNewItem() {
```

to

```
function addNewItem(list) {
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You've missed function parameter, list:

```
function addNewItem(list) {
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.innerText = "Hello";

    list.appendChild(listItem);
}


var btnNew = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
btnNew.onclick = function() {
    addNewItem(document.getElementById("todoList"));
};
```